# Яке походження слів «кермо», «кермувати»?

Tags: етимологія

Є іменник «кермо» і дієслово «кермувати». Яке їх походження і чи пов'язане воно якось зі словом «керувати»?

Щодо «керувати» я припускаю походження від польск. [kierować](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kierowa%C4%87) (хоча, звісно, необов'язково так — може, просто спільне слово чи щось інше), яке зводять до [kierunek](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kierunek), а те в свою чергу — до якогось німецького (написано [тут](http://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/kierunek#pl) з посиланням на «Історію мови польської» Зенона Клеменсевича <sub>(видавництво «PWN», Варшава, 2002, ст. 305)</sub>, але саме слово не вказане). Але щодо «кермо»/«кермувати» не знайшов нічого.

Тож яке походження слів «кермо»/«кермувати» і чи пов'язани вони якось зі словом «керувати»?

Comment: Чекаю коли вже настане час і відкинуть оці імперські закидони про запозичення з польської, німецької, або російської такі прадавні корені. Може, Фасмеру язик не повертався? А ну, задам питання.

Comment: @SassaNF, я просто припустив (якщо немає в східного сусіда — то може є в західного… є… раз є — то, значить, або запозичення, або спільне слово). Фасмера насправді і росіяни «звинувачують», що в нього «занадто все запозичене»; але все ж певною мірою авторитет. [Отут](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/291/4) іншу гіпотезу висувають; до речі, Я. Рудницький теж вважає, що це з [СВН](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Середньоверхньонімецька_мова) (або безпосередньо, або через поляків).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Згідно з етимологічним словником Наукової думки (том 2, сторінка 424) "кермо"/"кермувати" походять від слова "кирма" (велике стернове весло), "кирмувати" (працювати цим веслом). І зазнали змін під впливом "керувати", що є запозиченням з польської (тобто так, повʼязані, під впливом запозиченя перша голосна стала "е").

Слово "кирма" повʼязано напряму зі словом "корма", про яке в етимологічному словнику величезна стаття, яку я б стисло переказав так: ще в прасловʼянській мові було слово "k?ma" (не знаю, що це за другий символ), що вже означало "корма" й "стернове весло". А вже його походження "остаточно не зʼясоване", там багато версій, можна прочитати в третьому томі цього словника на сторінці 28.

Answer (score 5):

Гугл допоміг мені знайти дві версії:

- перша та ж, що і у Вас: від німецького *kehren* (повертати) (*die Kehre* - "повертач", себто руль) через польське *kierować*. Іменник *кермо* (це вже на мою власну думку) міг бути утворений із запозиченої основи *кер* за допомогою відносно рідкісного  суфіксу *-мо* (як в *пись-мо, пас-мо,* перепрошую, *дерь-мо*);
- друга версія складніша і давніша, тобто через більш давню праслов'янську чи навіть індоєвропейську основу ***кърм***, яка значила "відрізати, *кром*сати, відо*крем*лювати". Ланцюжок буцімто такий: при будуванні човна дошки обрізали - *кромили* - там, де планувався його зад; відповідно, там формувалася *крома/корма*. Там сидів *корм*чий/*керм*анич і працював, відповідно, *корм*илом/*керм*ом.

Власне, ця друга версія може включати в себе і першу, бо виглядає можливим, що німецьке *kehren* і слов'янське *корма* походять від спільної індоєвропейської основи ***кърм***.

Comment: хіба "дерь-мо" це українське слово?

Comment: Дуже цікава відповідь. Але було б добре, якби Ви підкріпили її хоч якимось джерелами. Наприклад, друге — це Ваша особиста версія, чи ні? (Якщо ні — скажіть, звідки вона, якщо так — покажіть, наприклад, де можна прочитати про індоєвропейську основу *кърм* і її значення.)

Comment: @s0nata: йдеться про *походження* слова, тобто про ті часи, коли українська мова ще не виділилася із загальнослов'янської. Слово "дерьмо", як пишуть етимологічні словники, походить від кореня "дерти, драти", який є і в українській мові.

Comment: @Sasha: NB: *відповідатиму по частинах, бо інтерфейс не дозволяє довгі тексти:( *
1) власне основу *kъrma* згадує і словник Фасмера, і словник Черних (на статтях "корма")
 http://www.slovorod.ru/etym-chernykh/_pdf/russ-hist-etym-chernykh-1.pdf
http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/query.cgi?basename=\data\ie\vasmer&root=config&morpho=0 (тут в пошуковик треба ввести слово "корма")
Черних припускає, що воно може походити від кореня ker - різати, Фасмер припускає, що воно може бути пов'язане з грецьким kormos - колода (а я в цьому бачу те ж таки "зрізане дерево").

Comment: @Sasha: 2) Словник Старостіна теж у статті про індоєвропейську основа *ker* ("різати") вказує на англійське "harm", тобто основа *ker* можа набути *m*
http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpokorny&text_number=+929&root=config
Індоєвропейський лексикон Pokorny теж згадує основу *ker* у значенні "to cut"
https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/semantic/field/PA_CU
Той же ж таки Фасмер на статті "крома́" (тобто "кроме", "відокремлене") теж згадує балтські і германські корені *(s) krm* у значенні "різати, ранити, кусати"

Comment: @Sasha: 3) Ланцюжок про *корму* як щось *відрізане* я побачив в оцій ненауковій статті http://otrok-ua.ru/ru/sections/art/show/o_proiskhozhdenii_oblakov.html
Але перевірив це припущення по словникам, і бачу, що це досить ймовірний зв'язок: ker(m)=різати => корма.

Comment: @Serhii, то навіщо Ви це тут пишете — додайте це у відповідь. Чи Ви просто не хочете її ускладнювати?

Answer (score 1):

Те «якесь» німецьке слово, від якого походять польські «kierować, kierunek» – це «kehren», *повертати(ся)* («Етимологічний словник української мови», [том 2](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.djvu), стор. 426, слово *керувати*). «Кермо» походить від «керувати» < «kierować» так само, як «гальмо» від «гальмувати», а «письмо» від «писати».

Comment: Власне, я таки примудрився знайти «Етимологічний словник української мови» — і там на ст. 424 написано, що кермо — це від слова «корма» (а «кермувати» — від «кермо» *під впливом* «керувати»). Тож, на жаль, -1.

Comment: @Sasha Я написав про це відповідь - і я помилявся :) Вибачаюся перед усіма, хто проголосував за неї. Зверніть увагу - там ке́рма, слова "кермо" там немає.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, так, але після «ке́рми» там відразу «кермо́», «кермови́й», «кермува́ти». Тобто, по-моєму, якраз у Вас все правильно. (Я припускаю, що «[ке́рма](http://sum.in.ua/s/kerma)» — це однокорінне слово, що на момент написання словника вважалося більш літературним, але зараз стало менш вживаним.)

Comment: @Sasha - Там відбулася контамінація «кéрма» та «керувати», та це не принципово, зв’язок із «керувати» важливіший, до того ж у «кермó» наголос такий, як і в інших _віддієслівних_ іменників з суфіксом -мó.

Comment: Yellow Sky, так в тому-то й справа, що за словником (якщо він, звісно, правий) «ке́рма» **не** пов'язане з «керувати»/«kierować»/«kehren» (а з «кормою»). А «керувати» лише вплинуло на **форму**, народивши дієслово «кермувати» — хоча **корінь** його теж, по суті, є нащадком «корми». Тобто і «ке́рма», і «кермо́», і «кермува́ти» є нащадками саме **«корми́»** (а «керування» лише сприяло появі форми «кермува́ти» і, можливо, «кермо́» — але аж ніяк не кореня). Чи я щось помилково інтерпретую (я не спеціаліст, щойно вперше той словник побачив)?