# Що саме за "плиг" у "збити з плигу"?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів

Як і в [сусідньому питанні](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/529/%d0%97%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%96%d1%88%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba) цікавить не значення цього фразеологізму, а його походження.

Із [*плигом*](http://sum.in.ua/s/plygh), начебто, все зрозуміло. Хоча *стрибок* його майже витіснив, але *плигати* досі активно вживається. Тому пояснити зворот можна приблизно так: я <sub>(думка?)</sub> збирався плигати в певному напрямку, але потім мене збили, і я вже не певний, куди саме далі.

Та потім я наштовхнувся на "збити з пливу" ([*збивати*<sup>7</sup>](http://sum.in.ua/s/zbyvaty)) (тобто ішов собі за течією, але потім мене збили) і трохи завагався, чи не могло відбутися *плив* ⇒ *плиг* ?

Comment: `плив` у цьому місці - іменник, і має інше значення. "ішов собі за течією, але мене збили"

Comment: @SassaNF, маєте на увазі, що "збити з плигу" ≠ "збити з пливу" ? Але СУМ-11 подає їх як ідентичні

Comment: ні, не маю на увазі, що різні. Просто пояснюю, що пояснення невірне, бо `плив` - не дієслово.

Comment: @SassaNF, я думаю, Nash Bridges і так знав, що «[плив](http://sum.in.ua/s/plyv)» (в даному контексті) — не дієслово (бо не можна сказати «збити з ходив/пірнав/<дієслово>»). Але Ваше пояснення очевидніше для читача, так. А іноді ще кажуть і «[збити з ходу](//books.google.com/books?id=a_8pAQAAIAAJ&q=%22збити+з+ходу%22)», але, мені здається, то може бути не зовсім той відтінок значення.

Comment: Взагалі, по-моєму, могли мати місце обидва фактори. Тобто на формування того з цих двох виразів («збити з пливу», «збити з плигу»), що усталився пізніше, могли впливати і пряме значення, і наявність схожого формулювання. Як от [*кермувати*](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/284/4) походить від *кърми*, але зазнало впливу схожого (ще раніше усталеного) дієслова *керувати*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова `плив` та `плиг` мають достатньо протилежні значення. Якщо вони мали б спільне походження, то у них би збереглися деякі схожі значення. Переглянемо тлумачні словники

[Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/125734/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3) - "Перун". 2005.

> I -у, ч., діал. Стрибок. || у знач. присл. пли́гом. Стрибками.
>
> II розм. Уживається як присудок за знач. плигати і плигнути.

[Там же](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/125736/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - `плигати`. Зауважте, що йдеться про різкі рухи, як у стрибках, а не про повільні, які пов'язані з плаванням.

> 1) Робити стрибок, стрибки; переміщуватися стрибками. || Стрибком
>   кидатися вниз. Плигати додолу. Плигати з парашутом. || Танцювати,
>   роблячи стрибки, підскакуючи. || Швидко текти по камінню, уступах і т.
>   ін. (про струмок, річку тощо). || Раз у раз пересуватися з місця на
>   місце (про відблиски, світло, тінь і т. ін.). || перен. Раз у раз
>   з'являтися і зникати в уяві, думках (про спогади, образи і т. ін.).
>
> 2) Ударяючись об що-небудь, відскакувати, підскакувати. || Різко
>   коливатися, тремтіти.

[Словарь української мови](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/39920-plygh-i.html) / Упор. з дод. влас. матеріалу Б. Грінченко : в 4-х т. — К. : Вид-во Академії наук Української РСР, 1958.
Том 3, ст. 195.

> Плиг! I   Прыгъ! скокъ!

У того ж [Гринченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/39916-plyv.html#show_point) `плив` - окреме слово з досить протилежним значенням до `плигу`

> Плив, -ву, м. 1) Теченіе. Час плив своїм пливом. МВ. ІІІ. 46. Чого
>   Дясна у шив пошла? Шо крутиї гори. Грин. III. 74. 2) збити з пливу.
>   Сбить съ толку. Усі одного зіб'ють з пливу. Н. Вол. у.

[Українсько - російський словник](http://books.dokladno.com/text.php?f=Uk-Ru_slovnyk_akademichnyi_tom3_1961_OCR&p=467)., Кириченко І. М. , Зайцева Т. В., Рильський М. Т. Видавництво Академії Наук Української РСР, Київ, 1958, 784 с.

Це ще один словник який дає протилежні тлумачення для `плив` та `плиг`. Цитувати усе не буду бо дуже багато тексту. Але наведу цитату з "Енеїди" (1798) Котляревського, яка доводить, що `збити з плигу` - дуже старий сталий вираз.

> Еней од страху з плигу збився.

Власне, `збити з плигу` та `збити з пливу`, принаймні на початку свого існування, мали означати стати на заваді різкого/імпульсивного або повільного/сталого процесу. Прижилося лише у контексті плигу/пливу думок і зараз означає [`спантеличувати`](http://sum.in.ua/s/spantelychuvaty) .